# Implement New-File-dialog like in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

I would like to implement a dialog in my App that behaves like the New-File-Dialog in Xcode. Here is an [image](http://d.pr/ALpO+).

It must

- docks to the toolbar
- allow me to set a custom view

Is it possible to place NSTextFields in there and return/access their values, when the user klicks the ok button?

I know that the e.g. NSSavePanel behaves similar but I don't find anything for raping it like at. You can set just a view for distributing a save-action.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using sheets. You should refer [Sheet Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html).